# 2D collisions and Resultant Velocities in Processing

Tags: processing, physics

I'm writing a simple program to detect collisions and give the appropriate resultant velocities. Whenever I add in the code that actually sets the resultant velocities, no objects render, just blink briefly on addition. I don't imagine it matters much that I'm using Processing, the syntax is pretty standard.

[The formulas I'm using](http://williamecraver.wix.com/elastic-equations)

```
for (int i =0; i<balls.length; i+=1) {
for (int j =0; j<balls.length; j+=1) {
  float x1 = balls[i].x;
  float y1 = balls[i].y;
  float vx1 = balls[i].vx;
  float vy1 = balls[i].vy;
  float m1 = balls[i].m;
  float size1 = balls[i].size;
  float x2 = balls[j].x;
  float y2 = balls[j].y;
  float vx2 = balls[j].vx;
  float vy2 = balls[j].vy;
  float m2 = balls[j].m;
  float size2 = balls[j].size;
  float v1=sqrt(pow(vx1, 2)+pow(vy1, 2));
  float v2=sqrt(pow(vx2, 2)+pow(vy2, 2));
  float t1=atan(x1/y1);
  float t2=atan(x2/y2);
  float c=atan((x2-x1)/(y2-y1));
  if (sqrt(sq(x2-x1)+sq(y2-y1)) < size1/2+size2/2) {
    balls[i].vx=cos(c)*((v1*cos(t1-c)*(m1-m2)+2*m2*v2*cos(t2-c))/(m1+m2))+v1*sin(t1-c)*cos(c+(PI/2));
    balls[i].vy=sin(c)*((v1*cos(t1-c)*(m1-m2)+2*m2*v2*cos(t2-c))/(m1+m2))+v1*sin(t1-c)*cos(c+(PI/2));
    balls[j].vx=cos(c)*((v2*cos(t2-c)*(m2-m1)+2*m1*v1*cos(t1-c))/(m1+m2))+v1*sin(t2-c)*cos(c+(PI/2));
    balls[j].vy=sin(c)*((v2*cos(t2-c)*(m2-m1)+2*m1*v1*cos(t1-c))/(m1+m2))+v1*sin(t2-c)*cos(c+(PI/2));
  }
  balls[i].draw();
  balls[j].draw();
}
```

Comment: You're trying to solve several problems at once. What happens if you try to draw the balls *without* changing their velocities? Can you draw a ball at all? (Also, I notice that your loops draw each ball many times, which might be the cause of the trouble.)

Comment: The folks over at the processing boards helped me out. When i==j, it's checking the same ball against itself and getting some ridiculous info. A simple
`if(i!=j) {` wrapper did the trick.

Comment: I also changed the code to draw the ball only (half?) as many times by removing `balls[j].draw();`, and just leaving `balls[i].draw();`

Answer (score 0):

The folks over at the processing boards helped me out. When `i==j`, it's checking the same ball against itself and getting some ridiculous info. A simple `if(i!=j) {` wrapper did the trick.